# Re index For specific product in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex

i want reindex for some products by id i tried following code but it take all indexing to reindex required i am using **magento 1.9.2.**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('84494'); // Product Id

$event = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->logEvent( $product,$product->getResource()->getType(), Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE,true );

Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')
    ->getProcessByCode('catalog_url') // Adjust the indexer process code as needed
    ->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)
    ->processEvent($event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
$productid = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);

$event = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->logEvent(
        $product,
        $product->getResource()->getType(),
        Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE,
        false );

    Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')
        ->getProcessByCode('catalog_url')
        ->setMode(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME)
        ->processEvent($event);
```

Comment: i tried this but its take all index to reindex reuired